# Alternate Between Two Colors For Text

Tags: python, button, tkinter, colors

Is there a way to switch the color of a button every time it's clicked (for example, it starts off white, the first time it's clicked it turns blue, the next time it's clicked it turns back to white, if it's clicked a third time it goes to blue again... And on and on in the same pattern).

If this is possible, is there a way for python to remember what color the button was the previous session, and stay that color the next time it's launched?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Here, the text color toggles from red to blue when the button is pressed.

If you change the keyword argument of the button option from `fg` to `bg`, you will, on certain systems (not on OSX) change the background color instead of the text color. Try it if you wish.

```
import tkinter as tk               # <-- avoid star imports


def toggle_color(last=[0]):        # <-- creates a closure to memoize the last value of the colors index used to toggle
    colors = ['red', 'blue']
    color = colors[last[0]]
    last[0] = (last[0] + 1) % 2    # <-- ensure the index is 0 or 1 alternatively
    btn.config(fg=color)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    btn = tk.Button(root, text='toggle', fg='blue', command=toggle_color)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do can change the color of the button as the button is pressed. There are several ways to do it. I have posted some snippets.

Here is a code:

```
from tkinter import * #for python2 Tkinter
global x
x = 0
root = Tk()
def b1c(): #this function will run on button press
    global x
    if x == 0:
        b1["bg"] = "blue"
        x += 1
    elif x == 1:
        b1["bg"] = "white"
        x = 0
b1 = Button(root,text="Press me to change the color",command = b1c) #making button
if x == 1:b1["bg"] = "white";x =0 
b1.place(x=1,y=1) #placing the button
mainloop()
```

The code above is a bit complex so if you want an easy way to do it then I have made another code. You can also change the colors of the button by changing the values of `color1` and `color2` *(currently white and blue)*:

```
from tkinter import * #for python2 Tkinter
root = Tk()

color1 = "white" #the default color
color2 = "blue" #the next color
def b1c(): #this function will run on button press
    if b1.cget("bg") == color2:b1["bg"] =color1  #getting current button color
    elif b1.cget("bg") == color1:b1["bg"] =color2 
b1 = Button(root,text="Press me to change the color",bg=color1,command = b1c)
b1.place(x=1,y=1) 
mainloop()
```

If you have a list of colors which you want to change one by one when the button is pressed then you can also do it. In the following code , the list is `colors`:

```
from tkinter import * #for python2 Tkinter
root = Tk()

colors = ["red","blue","green","sky blue"] #place your colors in it which you want to change 1-by-1 (from left to right)
def b1c():
    for colo in colors:
        if b1.cget("bg") == colo:
            try:
                color = colors[colors.index(colo)+1]
            except:
                color = colors[0]
            b1["bg"] = color
            break
b1 = Button(root,text="Press me to change the color",bg=colors[0],command = b1c)
b1.place(x=1,y=1) 
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the other answers, I'd suggest an Object Oriented approach. 
The below example uses the tkinter Button class as a basis but adds the `on_color` and `off_color` parameters to specify what color your want the button to be when it is on/off.

This way you can have as many buttons as you want that have similar behavior but without having to have a function to change the state of every button. This behavior is defined in the class instead.

`on_color` and `off_color` are optional parameters that will default to 'green' and 'red' respectively if not specified.

```
import tkinter as tk

def pressed():
    print("Pressed")

class ToggleButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        self.onColor = kw.pop('on_color','green')
        self.offColor = kw.pop('off_color','red')
        tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self['bg'] = self.offColor
        self.bind('<Button-1>',self.clicked)
        self.state = 'off'
    def clicked(self,event):
        if self.state == 'off':
            self.state = 'on'
            self['bg'] = self.onColor
        else:
            self.state = 'off'
            self['bg'] = self.offColor 


root = tk.Tk()
btn = ToggleButton(root,text="Press Me", on_color='blue',off_color='yellow',command=pressed)
btn.grid()

btn2 = ToggleButton(root,text="Press Me",command=pressed)
btn2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

In order to remember what state each button was in, you'll need to save a file on close and open it again on start up. In the past, I've done this by writing a JSON file containing a dictionary of all my settings. To do something when the application closes you can bind a function call to the window manager's delete window method

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.onClose)
```

This will call the `onClose` method of the `app` when the window is closed. Inside this method, you just collect up the various states of the buttons and write them to a file.  For example

```
settings = {}
settings['btn2_state'] = btn2.state
with open('settings.json','w') as settings_file:
    settings.write(json.dumps(settings))
```

This can then be read back in again when you open the program up again with something like

```
with open('settings.json','r') as settings_file:
    settings = json.load(settings_file)
btn2.state = settings['btn2_state']
```